# currentQuantity retaining the previous value even when variant is change

Tags: javascript, shopify

variants has rules on certain quantities. When currentQuantity matches the rule.qty it will display cancelled price and discounted price. So what happening it's for example we have two variants and both has rule for 3 qty like buy 3 get 10% off like. So when i updated the quantity to 3 its displaying cancelled price and discounted price for that varaint and when suddenly chnage to 2nd variant it's displaying cancelled price and discounted price for 2nd variant as 2nd variant also has rule on 3 qty. As currentQuantity is retaining previous value.

```
var oscpProductTemplate = {
    settings: {},
    init: function () {
        var $this = this;
        if (typeof oscpCPWAppConfig == "undefined") {
            eval(
                jQuery(document)
                    .find('script[type="text/oscpAppSetting"]')
                    .eq(0)
                    .text()
            );
        }

        //$this.settings = (typeof oscpCPWAppConfig == 'undefined') ? {} : JSON.parse(oscpCPWAppConfig);
        $this.settings =
            typeof oscpCPWAppConfig == "undefined" ? {} : oscpCPWAppConfig;

        jQuery(document).on("change", 'input[name="id"]', function (e) {
            if (typeof $this.settings.timer !== "undefined") {
                clearTimeout($this.settings.timer);
            }

            $this.settings.timer = setTimeout(function () {
                $this.setProductTemplate();
            }, 200);
        });
        document.addEventListener("cpw:product-init", function (evt) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $this.setProductTemplate();
            }, 200);
        });
        
        setTimeout(function () {
            $this.setProductTemplate();
        }, 1000);
    },
    sortQtyAscending: function (jsonData) {
        jsonData.forEach((item) => {
            item.rules.sort((a, b) => parseInt(a.qty) - parseInt(b.qty));
        });
        return jsonData;
    },

    setProductTemplate: function () {
        if (!this.settings.priceGrid[0].hasOwnProperty("rules")) {
            return;
        }

        $("#oscpPriceGrid").remove();

        var url = new URL(window.location.href);
        var variantId = url.searchParams.get("variant");

        if (variantId == null || variantId == "") {
            variantId = this.settings.priceGrid[0].id;
        }

        this.settings.priceGrid = this.sortQtyAscending(
            this.settings.priceGrid
        );


    
        var variantPrice = "";
        for (var v = 0; v < this.settings.product.variants.length; v++) {
            if (this.settings.product.variants[v].id == variantId) {
                variantPrice = this.settings.product.variants[v].price;
                
            }
        }

        var quantityInput = document.querySelector(
            "#Quantity-template--20089102827796__main"
        );
        
        

        var updatePrice = () => {
        
            

            var currentQuantity = quantityInput.value;
            console.log("Current Quantity:", currentQuantity);

            

            //Dynamically change cancelled price and discounted price
            // Loop through the priceGrid array
            for (var i = 0; i < this.settings.priceGrid.length; i++) {
                // Get the current priceGrid object
                var priceGrid = this.settings.priceGrid[i];
                // Get the id of the current priceGrid object
                var priceGridId = priceGrid.id;
                // Get the number of rules in the current priceGrid object
                var priceGridRuleLength = priceGrid.rules.length;

                // Check if the priceGrid id matches the variant id and there are rules present
                if (priceGridId == variantId && priceGridRuleLength > 0) {
                    // Initialize variables for cancelled price and discounted price
                    var cancelledPrice = 0;
                    var discountedPrice = 0;

                    // Loop through the rules in the current priceGrid object
                    for (r = 0; r < priceGridRuleLength; r++) {
                        // Get the value of the current rule
                        var Rulevalue = priceGrid.rules[r].value;

                    

                        if (currentQuantity == priceGrid.rules[r].qty) {
                            // Check the type of the current rule
                            if (priceGrid.rules[r].type == "percent") {
                                // If the rule type is percent, calculate cancelled and discounted prices accordingly
                                cancelledPrice = variantPrice;
                                discountedPrice =
                                    variantPrice * (1 - Rulevalue / 100);
                            } else {
                                // If the rule type is not percent, calculate cancelled and discounted prices accordingly
                                cancelledPrice = variantPrice;
                                discountedPrice = Rulevalue * 100;
                            }

                            $(".original-price del").text(
                                this.setMoneyFormat(cancelledPrice)
                            );
                            $(".discounted-price").text(
                                this.setMoneyFormat(discountedPrice)
                            );
                            break;
                        } else {
                            // If the quantity is not equal to the rule quantity, calculate cancelled and discounted prices accordingly
                            $(".original-price del").empty();
                            $(".discounted-price").empty();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    // Exit the loop
                    break;
                } else if (
                    priceGridId != variantId &&
                    priceGrid.rules == null
                ) {
                    // If the priceGrid id doesn't match the variant id and there are no rules present,
                    // log "Rule not found" to the console and exit the loop
                    console.log("Rule not found");
                    break;
                } else {
                    // If none of the above conditions are met, log the variant id to the console
                    // and empty the original-price and discounted-price elements in the UI
                    console.log("Variant else id: ", variantId);
                    $(".original-price del").empty();
                    $(".discounted-price").empty();
                }
            }
        }

        
    
        quantityInput.addEventListener("change", updatePrice);
    

    

        // Call the function wherever else you need the dynamic behavior
        updatePrice();
        //End OF Dynamically change cancelled price and discounted price


        
    
     

        



        for (var j = 0; j < this.settings.priceGrid.length; j++) {
            if (
                this.settings.priceGrid[j].id == variantId &&
                this.settings.priceGrid[j].rules.length
            ) {
                $(".cpw-product__price").html(
                    "<s data-compare-price>" +
                        this.setMoneyFormat(variantPrice) +
                        '</s> <span class="" data-price=""> ' +
                        this.setMoneyFormat(
                            this.settings.priceGrid[j].rules[0].value * 100
                        ) +
                        "</span>"
                );

                var qtybreakHtml =
                    "<table id='oscpPriceGrid'><tr><th>Qty</th><th>Price</th></tr>";
                for (i = 0; i < this.settings.priceGrid[j].rules.length; i++) {
                    var rowPrice = this.settings.priceGrid[j].price;
                    var rowrules = this.settings.priceGrid[j].rules[i];

                    rowrules.type =
                        rowrules.type == "discount" ? "percent" : rowrules.type;

                    var price = this.getLineItemPrice(
                        rowPrice * 100,
                        rowrules,
                        1
                    );
                    //var price = [10,20,30];
                    var Pricerules =
                        rowrules.type == "percent"
                            ? rowrules.value + " " + "%   OFF"
                            : this.setMoneyFormat(rowrules.value * 100) +
                              "   each";

                    qtybreakHtml +=
                        "<tr><td>" +
                        "Buy " +
                        this.settings.priceGrid[j].rules[i].qty +
                        "</td><td>" +
                        Pricerules +
                        "</td></tr>";
                }
                qtybreakHtml += "</table>";

                $("#oscpPriceGridContainer").append(qtybreakHtml);
            }
        }
    },
    getLineItemPrice: function (price, rule, rules, qty) {
        // Return calculated (line item price, line item total price and saving amount)
        price = parseInt(price);
        rule.type = rule.type == "discount" ? "percent" : rule.type;
        var rowValue =
            rule.type == "percent"
                ? parseFloat(rule.value)
                : parseFloat(rule.value) * 100;
        if (rule.type == "percent") {
            var calulatedPrice = price - (price * rowValue) / 100;
            var save = rowValue.toFixed(2) + "%";
        } else {
            var calulatedPrice = rowValue;
            var save = (100 * (price - rowValue)) / price;
            save = save.toFixed(2);
            save = save + "%";
        }
        var calulatedTotalPrice = calulatedPrice * qty;

        return [calulatedPrice, calulatedTotalPrice, save, rules];
    },
    setMoneyFormat: function (amount) {
        // Provission to show price with proper currency and template
        amount = amount / 100;
        amount = amount.toFixed(2);
        return this.settings.priceTemplate.replace("0", amount);
    },
};

if (!window.jQuery) {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = "//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js";
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
    script.readyState &&
    (script.readyState == "loaded" || script.readyState == "complete")
        ? (script.onreadystatechange = function () {
                oscpProductTemplate.init();
          })
        : (script.onload = function () {
                oscpProductTemplate.init();
          });
} else {
    oscpProductTemplate.init();
}
```

What i want is when currentquantity matches rule qty display cancelled price and discounted price.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research.  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.